# Do the DC speedsters need to accelerate and are not fast from the start like Quicksilver in the movies?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, arrowverse, the-flash

Why doesn't Flash in the new show "The Flash" simply dodge attacks like Quicksilver did in the movies by speeding up and even changing trajectories of bullets?

According to [these](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84272/why-is-the-flash-always-so-slow-in-key-moments) two [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12000/why-isnt-the-flash-unstoppable) about the Flash it is because he is new to it, basically a noob. And according to [this question](https://www.quora.com/Who-is-faster-The-Flash-or-Quiksilver) *The Flash is faster that Quicksilver*. Also according to [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52062/why-doesnt-the-flash-have-lightning-fast-reactions) it is for making a proper story as he could simply defeat everyone (which answers most of my query).

**So my question is that do DC speedsters get faster as they start running and accelerate and also if Quicksilver and similar in Marvel are instantly fast?**

Note: Please restrict answers to the scope here (in context to movie and TV characters and not comics).

Comment: The Flash is faster than Quicksilver *in the comics*; we have no idea how fast Quicksilver is, but Barry Allen on TV is orders of magnitude slower than Barry Allen in the comics.

Comment: @KutuluMike But still won't he simply see it in slow motion like when an enitre bookshelf is throw on him and other things and simply walk away just like quicksilver does in the movies(X-men movies mainly).Anyway I wanted to know a different thing(.The part in the bold text.)

Comment: Then I think your question is written in a confusing way... are you asking if speedsters are *always* seeing things at high speed even when they are standing still?

Comment: @KutuluMike Exactly.Sorry about not knowing enough of DC though.That is what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The show is inconsistent with Barry's speed. One episode has him moving fast enough to have a one sided conversation with out Iris hearing or seeing him. He also catches things by reflex (falling coffee mug). But he's often caught by surprise. Most of the time, he has to actively enable his speed force based powers for him to move or focus at super speed. When he does, his eyes flash with Speed-Force lightning.

[Quicksilver in most media is always at super speed, as I mentioned in the other answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52062/why-doesnt-the-flash-have-lightning-fast-reactions) He doesn't tap into a speed force, he has natural genetic quickness. In X-Men, he's significantly ADHD, and in MCU, he even sees a bullet shot from under him (but he can't react in time since he wasn't paying attention to it below him)

That said, there is multiple instances of Barry, Eobard, and Zoom catching bullets in mid air. Barry for example when Papa Snart shot him, he caught the bullet in his hand while pretending to have been shot. Zoom when The entire CCPD shot at him. Zoom also pretty much recreates the X-men Quick Silver scene when he kills half the CCPD on both Earth 1 and Earth 2, immediately snapping all their necks, so they all fall at the same time.

Barry doesn't do this because he is hampered by the Good Guy Idiot Ball, and as you mentioned, is plot dumb. That said, he swoops in and takes out a huge crowd of Meta humans from Earth-2 in the second to last episode, essentially like zoom did, just not fatally.

### Update:

To provide a comparison, Barry Allen in ***The Flash*** has rescued buildings full of people while one building is on fire (S01E02), and later when another building collapses (S02E22). ***X-Men Apocalypse*** shows Quicksilver do the same to a mansion full of people while the mansion explodes. The only difference being the special effects budget used to show this happening. The end result was the same, a group of people single handedly saved by the speedsters, ***initiated by a split second reaction to building destruction events***.

Comment: Even though ignoring the inconsistencies,you say the Speedsters get fast gradually ,as they tap into the speed force ?Is this conclusion correct.

Comment: @Ishan I'm saying that they have to want to be fast, like switching it on. It's an active power, not a passive one.

Comment: I *think* the idea is supposed to be that Barry (etc.) don't always see things at Speed-Force speed, but they can activate it so instinctively that (e.g.) as soon as he sees a cup falling, he can turn on his speed fast enough to catch it. At least that's the best explanation I can come up with.

Comment: @IshanTaneja "gradually" is not the right word. DC speedsters can go from zero to "really fast" instantly. That said, at least in the Arrowverse, Barry has frequently been shown to "ramp up" his speed, but that is typically when he is pushing himself to go faster than he had ever previously run.